# Group By and Counting inside group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario in which I want to count records after grouping the data. (Actual scenario contains multiple tables.)

```
create table tblXYZ
(
id int,
Age int,
Typ char
)
```

Table contains this data:

```
| ID | Age  | Typ
------------------
| 1  | 20   | A
| 2  | 20   | A
| 3  | 21   | B
| 4  | 22   | B
| 5  | 22   | A
| 6  | 23   | B
| 7  | 23   | A
| 8  | 23   | A
| 9  | 25   | B
| 10 | 25   | B
| 11 | 25   | A
```

If I apply a group by Age, I'll get:

```
| Age  | Typ_Count
-------------
| 20   | 2
| 21   | 1
| 22   | 2
| 23   | 3
| 25   | 3
```

But I want to get the typ_count based on every specific typ for every age group.

Desired result:

```
    | Age  | Typ_A_Count | Typ_B_Count
    ---------------------------------
    | 20   | 2           | 0
    | 21   | 0           | 1
    | 22   | 1           | 1
    | 23   | 2           | 1
    | 25   | 1           | 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: please post your attempt

Comment: You could use a pivot if the types are static or a dynamic pivot to achieve this

Comment: Do they have to be in different columns?  can't you just group by age and typ?  If they have to be in columns use a case statement for each type.  If you have an random number of types, then you need to write a dynamic Piviot such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query.  Too many unknown factors to make a "quality" recommendation at this time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can count multiple categories like this:

```
SELECT
    Age,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Typ = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS CountTypA,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Typ = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS CountTypB
FROM tblXYZ
GROUP BY Age
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT Age,Typ
FROM tblXYZ
PIVOT
(
 count (Typ) FOR Typ IN ('A','B')
)
```